# How do I connect containers from multiple servers with cadvisor to prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, cadvisor

How do I connect containers from multiple servers with cadvisor to prometheus? Like the promtail for Grafana Loki.
All the tutorials are like everything is on localhost.

Answer (score 2):

Your question lacks detail and an explanation of how you've tried to solve this problem yourself, it will likely be closed.

Prometheus' documentation is decent. I encourage to read the [getting started](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/getting_started/) and to review the [configuration](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/).

Prometheus **scrapes** targets (endpoints) to retrieve a list of metrics either directly or indirectly (using an intermediate service discovery mechanism).

cAdvisor publishes Prometheus metrics on `/metrics` ([link](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/storage/prometheus.md)).

The simplest solution for you would be to enumerate your cAdvisor hosts as a set of [`static_config`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#static_config) targets:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 1m
  evaluation_interval: 1m

scrape_configs:
  # Self
  - job_name: "prometheus-server"
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - "localhost:9090"

  # cAdvisor hosts
  - job_name: "cadvisor"
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - "[cAdvisor-host-01]:[port]"
          - "[cAdvisor-host-02]:[port]"
          - "[cAdvisor-host-XX]:[port]"
```

And then run Prometheus with this configuration:

```sh
docker run \
--interactive \
--rm \
--net=host \
--publish=9090:9090 \
--volume=${PWD}/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:v2.33.5 \
--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
  --web.enable-lifecycle
```